# VBA Dynamic Range Formula NOT Set in Range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with my code. I run a simple VBA code with userform and in one of the workbook's worksheet I run my formula in specific range in specific columns. Somehow, and I dont know why, the code runs on this lines without some error but the cells stay as it was without formula when the code ends. If someone could analyze me problem here in columns AC and AD i will be greatful.

here is the specific lines of code, the problem is Just with columns AC, AD:

```
    VLR = MainWB.Worksheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With MainWB.Worksheets(5)
    UniqueLRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
End With

'Column AC
With MainWB.Worksheets(2)
    .Range("AC2").Activate
    .Range("AC2:AC" & VLR).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIF(Unique!R2C5:R " & UniqueLRow & " C5,visual!RC[-2]),1,"""")"
End With

HourLR = MainWB.Worksheets(6).Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

'Column AD
With MainWB.Worksheets(2)
    .Range("AD2:AD" & VLR).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIF(HourCommissions!R2C5:R " & HourLR & " C5,visual!RC[-3])>0,1,"""")"
End With
```

Comment: Did you try to debug code using `F8` and step through it. It will be good to add `.select` for seeing what it is executing.

Comment: Are you using `On Error Resume Next` somewhere before the code you showed in the description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try and see if that resolves your issue...

```
With MainWB.Worksheets(2)
    .Range("AC2", "AC" & VLR).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIF(Unique!R2C5:R" & UniqueLRow & "C5,visual!RC[-2]),1,"""")"
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

here;

```
.Range("AD2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AB2:AB" & VLR), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Destination is the range in active sheet. It will work if only it is Worksheet(2). Do you want this or just forget dot before Range?

Comment: yes I use on error resume next in the start of the code once. to delete it?

Comment: if it still do not work, remove on error resume next. You will at least know where is an error.